HCPL2531 offset voltage status at opto output
I am testing in a panel with very high motor noise. I want to pass the encoder data through the opto. When I apply the following scheme, my inputs and outputs are as I want.

Giriş

Çıkış 
Then I switch to the scheme as below (mandatory). My input signal is the same but my output signal stays at a certain offset.

new output signal 
How can I eliminate this offset? When I play with the resistor values, the circuit gets a bit ridiculous. For example, I make the resistors 100R, 680R, 100R for one channel and this time there is a voltage drop at the output.
GND isolation right now, my goal is to get the signal I want first.
Example voltage drop output signal 

The HCPL2531 has specified characteristics only for a LED current of 16 mA, and in that case, has a worst-case current transfer ratio of less than 20 %. So a HCPL2531 output is not guaranteed to be capable of driving a HCPL2531 input.
You can either add an amplifier between the two optocouplers (a single transistor per signal should suffice), or use digital optocouplers with a more sensitive input, e.g., H11L1.
